# Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity

Tags: hibernate, web, lucene, tapestry, hibernate-search

I am doing some web app with hibernate, hibernate search, lucene and tapestry. Now, everything is OK, until I have deployed this part of code into my app. I keep getting this error

```
Render queue error in SetupRender[Index:layout.listarticles.grid]: Failure reading parameter 'source' of component Index:layout.listarticles.grid: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
```

even though I have denoted my Article class with @Indexed annotation as specified. What may cause this issue? May my inherited classes cause this issue, since my Article is a top of many other subclasses, and HS or Lucene can't provide polymorhic search or what? I am stuck on this for half an hour now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ListArticles {


    @Property
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Article article;
    @Inject
    private Session hibernate;
    @SessionState // changed from ApplicationState
    @Property
    private User user;
    @Property
    private boolean ifUserExists;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ListArticles.class);
    @Inject
    private HibernateSessionManager hibernateSessionManager;
    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String searchText;

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return list
     */
    @CommitAfter
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Article> getArticles() {

        if (article != null) {

            return hibernate.createCriteria(Article.class).list();
        } else if (searchText != null && searchText.trim().length() > 0) {
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(hibernateSessionManager.getSession());
            try {
                fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                logger.warn("Lucene Indexing was interrupted by something " + e);
            }

            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Article.class).get();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
                    .keyword()
                    .onFields("name, desc")
                    .matching(searchText)
                    .createQuery();

            return fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Article.class).list();
        } else {
            // default - unfiltered - all entitites list 
            return hibernate.createCriteria(Article.class).list();

        }
    }
     // 1520 lines of code trimmed using Built-in plugin CodeTrimmer
```

My ListArticles.tml file looks like following

```
<PostDisplay xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
        <p>${message:newestArticles}</p>
         <form t:type="Form" t:id="searchForm">
                <input t:type="TextField" t:id="searchText" size="30" value="searchText" />    
                <t:submit t:id="search" value="Search" /><t:submit t:id="clear" value="Clear/Show All" />  

            </form>
        <t:grid source="articles" row="article" include="name, desc" >
        <p:nameCell>${article.name}</p:nameCell>
        <p:descriptionCell>${article.desc}</p:descriptionCell>
         <p:empty>
           <p>No articles could be found!</p>
         </p:empty>
      </t:grid>
    </PostDisplay>
```

And my Article.java class looks like

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Article")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name="ART_TYPE",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @Indexed(index="indexes/essays")
    public abstract class Article
    {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ART_ID")
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ART_NAME")
    @Field
    private String name;


    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "ART_DESC")
    @Field
    private String desc;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "ART_IMAGE")
    @Field
    private String image;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "ART_TYPE")
    @Field
    private String articleType; // hard-coded, make it more pro

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "ART_SUBTYPE")
    @Field
    private String articleSubType; // hard-coded, make it more pro

    //to change or not to change this ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Collection<Picture> collectionOfPictures;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    private Collection<StarRates> collectionOfStarRates;  

    //148 lines of code trimmed using Built-in plugin CodeTrimmer
```

Comment: Oh, I have solved this! I just can't believe on what I have spent almost 40 mins. I had to properly declare all indexing instances of all my subclasses to their initiative calls.

Comment: If you want to @Inject FullTextSession instead of what you are doing here, add the following to your AppModule https://gist.github.com/uklance/5582542